# MySQL insert without duplicates from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, an empty one and one with data. I want to insert into empty one data from the other, without duplicates. 
Tables:

```
TABLE T1
    AutoNo INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    p1 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    p2 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (AutoNo),
    UNIQUE KEY `ppp` (p1,p2) //this one is empty, no records

TABLE T2
    AutoNo INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    q1 DATE NOT NULL,
    q2 TIME NOT NULL,
    q3 VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    q4 VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (AutoNo)
```

What i need is to take columns q3 and q4, and put in p1 and p2, but the combination of q3 and q4 must not be a duplicate (first occurrence is fine to copy, the others are not welcomed).

I used:

```
INSERT INTO T1 (p1, p2)
SELECT q3, q4
FROM T2
LEFT JOIN T1 ON 
   T1.p1= T2.q3 AND
   T1.p2= T2.q4
WHERE T1.p1 IS NULL AND T1.p2 IS NULL;
```

for this one i get an error code `#1062:Duplicate entry 'xxxx' for key q3`.

And i also tried:

```
INSERT INTO T1(p1, p2)
SELECT q3, q4
FROM T2
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT AutoNo FROM T1 
   WHERE T1.p1 = T2.q3 AND 
         T1.p2 = T2.q4);
```

and i get the same `#1062:Duplicate entry 'xxxx' for key q3` error.

Any help or suggestion would be much obliged.

Comment: use distinct function for q3 become distinct(q3)

Comment: Insert ignore will be fine

Comment: Forget T1 and the `INSERT`, how do you select all the data from T2 without duplicates? Once you can do that your problem is solved.

Comment: @Strawberry ignore is not accepted, errors will transform into warning, and i can't have neither at execute

Comment: I can't replicate that behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `select distinct`:

```
INSERT INTO T1(p1, p2)
    SELECT DISTINCT q3, q4
    FROM T2;
```

The `NOT EXISTS` version does not see the modified table.  It only sees the empty table.

Although I prefer the above, an alternative is to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO T1(p1, p2)
    SELECT q3, q4
    FROM T2
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 13 = VALUES(13);
```

This clause is essentially a no-op -- nothing gets done but the error in the unique index is ignored.

Comment: For `distinct` i get `Data truncated for column p2 at row ...` and for `on duplicate key` an `Unknown column q3 in field list`

Comment: @MRM . . . The truncation error is because the columns in the tables have different types.  You can use `left(q3, 20), left(q4, 20)` if the intention is to take the first 20 characters.

Comment: Yep, you were right, i forgot to increase the number of varchars for each column. Now it work. Thank you very much!